# PostGIS 3D spatial join (point in cube)

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial, spatial-query

I have a table, A, that contains point data (POINT Z) and another, B, with cubes (POLYHEDRALSUFRACE Z).

These are large tables, tens of millions of rows.
There are indexes on the geometry columns on both tables.
It is known that any point in A is contained in at most 1 cube in B.

Is it possible to perform a spatial join from A to B where the point on A is contained within the cube in B?

I can't seem to find a PostGIS function that would allow this. I was hoping that ST_3DIntersects would do it but it does not, for example:

```
select ST_3dIntersects(ST_MakePoint(42865, 164325, 795),
                       ST_GeomFromText('POLYHEDRALSURFACE(((42860 164320 792,42870 164320 792,42870 164320 796,42860 164320 796,42860 164320 792)),((42860 164320 796,42870 164320 796,42870 164330 796,42860 164330 796,42860 164320 796)),((42860 164330 792,42870 164330 792,42870 164330 796,42860 164330 796,42860 164330 792)),((42860 164320 792,42870 164320 792,42870 164330 792,42860 164330 792,42860 164320 792)),((42860 164320 792,42860 164330 792,42860 164330 796,42860 164320 796,42860 164320 792)),((42870 164320 792,42870 164330 792,42870 164330 796,42870 164320 796,42870 164320 792)))'))
```

returns false

I did notice that

```
select ST_3dIntersects(ST_MakePoint(42865, 164325, 795),
                       ST_3DMakeBox(ST_MakePoint(42860, 164320, 792), ST_MakePoint(42870, 164330, 796)))
```

returns true but that's a box3d object not a geometry.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `ST_3DDistance` suggests no containment: `SELECT ST_3DDistance(ST_MakePoint(42865, 164325, 795),
                     ST_GeomFromText('POLYHEDRALSURFACE(((42860 164320 .... '))`

Comment: Thanks Jim. Therein lies the problem. The cube is a surface, the point lies centrally in that cube but does not touch the surface. So 3DInstersects returns false.

Comment: oh I see.. 3D operations are indeed tricky :D